# How to deal with 401 Unauthorized response i Jmeter V3.0 or lower?

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-401, http-authentication

I am trying to login the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth using admin:admin as credentials.

I am using Jmeter v3.0 and I added HTTP Authorization manager, Cookie manager and also added the name and value in header manager as shown in the image, but I am still getting 401 unauthorized response.

I tried the same thing in a different system with Jmeter v3.1 and its working.

Does anyone know how to resolve issue with Jmeter v3.0 or lower?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem using JMeter 3.0 and only having [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) added apart from the HTTP Request:

[image]

Here is a full [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.9" jmeter="3.0 r1743807">
<hashTree>
  <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
    <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
    <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
    <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
      <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
  </TestPlan>
  <hashTree>
    <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
      <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
      <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1500191430000</longProp>
      <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1500191430000</longProp>
      <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
      <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
    </ThreadGroup>
    <hashTree>
      <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">the-internet.herokuapp.com</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/basic_auth</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
      </HTTPSamplerProxy>
      <hashTree>
        <AuthManager guiclass="AuthPanel" testclass="AuthManager" testname="HTTP Authorization Manager" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="AuthManager.auth_list">
            <elementProp name="" elementType="Authorization">
              <stringProp name="Authorization.url"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.username">admin</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.password">admin</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.domain"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Authorization.realm"></stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </AuthManager>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

I would recommend removing your `Authorization` header from the HTTP Header Manager just in case.

See [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for more details on bypassing basic access authentication in JMeter tests.

---

It is hightly recommended to use the latest JMeter versions where possible as newer versions normally come with bug fixes, performance improvements and brand new features so consider upgrading to JMeter 3.2 (or whatever is the latest version available at the [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Thanks for your response Dmitri. I removed Authorization header from the HTTP Header Manager and used HTTP Authorization manager.
the below are the details of my Authorization manager.
url= "the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth" username"admin" password"admin"   mehcnism"BASIC_DIGEST" 
are the details correct.

Comment: removing your Authorization header from the HTTP Header Manager worked for me! I don't know why